# How to give jdbc connection in gatling

Tags: gatling

```
val testData2 = jdbcFeeder("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.86.55.77:7777:studiodb", "sample", "sample", """

insert into  RunRecords(username,password) values('mohana','priya')""")
```

While simulating , Values are inserted but I am getting " Invalid SQL statement" error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to pass a SELECT SQL query!!!
http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.2/session/feeder.html#jdbc-feeder